# avoid user access speed getting slow if the amount of visitors are increaed

Tags: e-commerce

For an ecommerce website, if the number of the visotor is keeping increasing, the user acces speed on the website are getting slow.

Is there any solution to avoid user access speed becoming slow if the amount of visitors are increaed.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the answer depends on many variables. Probably too many. 
First of all it depends on these factors:

1. The software used for the site (it is something written from scratch, something you bought, an open source project for ecommerce?)
2. It depends on the bandwidth available  (you can increase it if needed)
3. It depends on the quality of the code (i saw some software that when loading some pages it  loads several tables in it, causing the page loading very slowly)
4. It depends on the hardware, how many session it can handles concurrently.
   etc.

Obviously if the number of users is growing of few units then probably there are some problems with the software (configuration? bad software? and so on).

Probably if you provide more details, the answer could be more accurate.